# extreme value function in R

Tags: r

I'm studying the an extreme value problem on http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Krijnen-IntroBioInfStatistics.pdf 
follows the An interesting extreme value distribution is given by Pevsner (2003, p.103)

I tried to generate a sample (with size 1000) from the standard normal distribution and repeated for 1000 times. Then, subtract the given function from these maxima an and divide by bn, where

fn <- `exp(-n)*exp(-exp(-n))`

an <- `sqrt(2*log(n)) - 0.5*(log(log(n))+log(4*pi))*(2*log(n))^(-1/2)`

bn <- `(2*log(n))^(-1/2)`

```
> my.stat <-NULL 
> for (i in 1:1000) { 
+  n <- rnorm(1000)
+   fn <- exp(-n)*exp(-exp(-n)) 
+   an <- sqrt(2*log(n)) - 0.5*(log(log(n))+log(4*pi))*(2*log(n))^(-1/2)
+   bn <- (2*log(n))^(-1/2)
+ my.stat <- c(my.stat, sum(sum(fn-an)/bn)))
> par(mfrow=c(2,2))
> hist(my.stat,freq=FALSE,main="histogram of 1000 M",xlab="M")
```

Error: object 'fn' not found???? i'm more concerned how to deal with the

```
+ my.stat <- c(my.stat, sum(sum(fn-an)/bn)))
```

part in the loop, since i stored all the sample values in a vector my.stat. And try to compute (fn-an)/bn during each loop.

I guess my question is is there a better way that i can add (fn-an)/bn to my vector each time in my for loop? Essentially, i want the my.stat to store all the (fn-an)/bn values. thanks.

Comment: you just need to close the brace on the for loop `}` and remove a `)`. still, you're trying to take the log of negative numbers in there...

Comment: @timriffe and then it pops out a lot of warnings

Comment: those warnings are mostly because n has negative numbers in it and you're taking the log of those, producing `NaN` values.

Comment: also it looks like you're not following the directions in that text: you're supposed to take the maximum of `rnorm(1000)`, 1000 times. The rest is for you

Comment: @timriffe OH i see! That's why. thanks.